# jQuery initialization with form id

Tags: jquery

I'm working with Composite Components in JSF and ran into troubles regarding JavaScript that I need to use. I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#form_test\\:text_auto").bind("keyup",function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
         send_ajax();
      }, 500);
   });
});
```

In order to be able to use this in different places, with different form ids and not prependId=false; I need to somehow initialize the script with the form id (in this example "form_test").

Binding the events like "keyup" using jQuery works well, so if possible I'd like to continue using that mechanism. Is it possible to somehow set the form id dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   bindKeyupOnForm("form_test");
});

function bindKeyupOnForm(formId) {
    $("#" + formId + "\\:text_auto").bind("keyup",function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            send_ajax();
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks sp00m. Having read up a bit on jQuery and tested different solutions, I believe yours is the best.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form\\:text_auto").bind("keyup",function() {  // this will apply for each form tag
    // if you need something from the form use $(this) variable  
    setTimeout(function() {
        send_ajax();
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need to have the specific form id as I will need to use that for other Components as well.

Comment: you can have the form id `$(this).attr('id')` :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. However, I found another way to solve it through setting the form id #(cc.attrs.formId) directly in the scripts.